# Um background é carregado mesmo quando uma regra não é aplicada sobre um elemento?

Tags: css

Não sei se o título da pergunta é clara, vou tentar explicar o mais claramente possível. Eu estou estudando sobre sites responsivos e tento ao máximo não usar imagens grandes para o site não ficar lento. Vi que posso criar versões de tamanhos diferentes de uma imagem e dependendo do tamanho do dispositivo, colocá-las em um objeto.

Assim, ao invés de carregar uma imagem com 5000px de largura e fazer ela se redimensionar de acordo com o tamanho do elemento dessa forma:

```
#elemento {
  background-image:url('imagem.png'); /* Imagem com 5000px de largura */
  background-size:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Eu posso fazer isso:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #elemento {
    background-image:url('imagem600.png'); /* Imagem com 600px de largura */
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #elemento {
    background-image:url('imagem900.png'); /* Imagem com 900px de largura */
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  #elemento {
    background-image:url('imagem1300.png'); /* Imagem com 1300px de largura */
  }
}
```

### A pergunta

Ao ter um dispositivo com 900px de largura, somente a imagem correspondente irá carregar ou todas irão ser baixadas? Se todas forem baixadas, tem alguma forma para o usuário que tenha um dispositivo pequeno não tenha que baixar uma imagem muito gigante desnecessariamente?

Comment: Só é "baixada" a imagem indicada na `@media` que corresponde ao ecrã do visitante porque só o conteúdo dessa `@media` é que vai ser lido!

Comment: Então a imagem só irá ser baixada caso um usuário que esteja usando um computador redimensionar a janela? Logo, não existe a possibilidade de por exemplo, alguém que esteja acessando o site por um celular baixar 5mb em imagens, certo?

Comment: ..... Certo! .....

Comment: Os pontinhos no comentário anterior é só porque o sistemas não deixa comentar com tão poucos caracteres. Este comentário é só para chatear até alguém apagar!

Comment: Muito obrigado, pelo menos com isso não devo me preocupar mais. Coloque como resposta para eu marcá-la!

Comment: Vou responder, estou a elaborar o assunto em maior detalhe para clarificar algumas coisas associadas a este tema. Entretanto também outras respostas poderão surgir para melhor clarificar a duvida :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comportamento varia de navegador para navegador, embora seja algo em constante melhoria.

Um artigo muito interessante:

## [Media Query & Asset Downloading Results](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/)

<sup>Em Inglês, publicado em 10-04-2012</sup>

e com testes relativamente exaustivos permite-nos apurar que para evitar o download de múltiplas imagens quando só vamos apresentar uma, a técnica ideal é definir a imagem nas diversas declarações `@media`:

[image: Captura de tela (alterada)]

Da forma que tens as tuas declarações de CSS, só uma imagem é descarregada porque a declarada na `@media` em uso subscreve a necessidade das outras.